# How to prevent a user from spending tokens he receives?

Tags: erc-20

Is there a way to prevent a user from spending tokens he receives? I guess one way is a timelock contract but a solution were tokens remain in the owners wallet is more preferable.

Also, please note that I should have no control over the token's contract.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do so would be to wrap the token you want to send the user with another token that you control. For example, instead of sending them USDT you would send them something like wUSDT that maps 1-to-1 to USDT, and then you lock those wUSDT in their account so that they can't send them anywhere. And once unlocked, they could swap them 1-to-1 for USDT.

But this is not a great solution in my opinion. What I would do instead is to implement a vesting contract that locks the tokens and gradually allows for them to be released with time. Such a contract could be implemented with OpenZeppelin's VestingWallet, which is documented here: https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/finance#VestingWallet

Comment: Thanks for the reply. To be specific, what I want to do is to prevent a user from spending staking rewards and yields he receives from staking/farming his tokens. I think your proposal comes closer to having him delegate the tokens in a contract and then using that contract as an intermediate that does the staking. However I would prefer if he didn't have to stake outside his wallet.

Comment: It's not possible to control tokens that are in the user's wallet unless you created that token.